# How to execute drop table query with if exists in sql server 2008 R2 in Java

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run an `IF exists' SQL query with statement.executeUpdate(query)` in java. Query executes fine if I directly run in SQL server management studio but did not work with executeupdate(query) function and gave me the error `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.` exception.

The Query which I am executing is:-

```
 IF EXISTS(select * from sysobjects where name='tblname') drop table tblname
```

Can anyone let me know If I am missing something in the query?post

Comment: Add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` before query to prevent sql server from sending x row(s) affected message back to Java.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`Statement.execute(String sql)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29) instead of the way you are executing it now. This doesn't expect a resultset be returned.

If you have a `PreparedStatement` on which you execute the SQL, use  [`PreparedStatement.execute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29).